# Please explaing IntelliJ IDEA's folders bin, assets and libs

Tags: intellij-idea

Could someone (crazycoder or other team member) from IntelliJ's team explain the intention of the following folders in IntelliJ Android project: /bin, /assets, /libs.

I can assume that the /libs is used for external libraries, and I saw that /assets has been used for storing PhoneGap files. I have never seen usage of bin folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a common Android project structure not specific to IntelliJ IDEA.

- **assets** folder is for raw resources that your application can access via [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html).
- **libs** is a common place for native libraries (.so files built with NDK).
- **bin** folder used as output directory by the Ant build of the Android project and is created automatically by Android SDK. IDEA doesn't use this folder

IDEA allows to customize locations of libs and assets folders in **Android Facet** settings.

Comment: Where do you suggest I keep .jar libraries?

Comment: It doesn't matter, I use the same libs folder for jars.

Comment: Thanks. I have problem with a certain library (my other question) and I wanted to be sure that the location of .jar file isn't making it.